# Passing a pointer to void as the second argument to pthread_join

Tags: c, pthreads

Below is an example program from the "Thread" section of "Advanced Linux Programming", with slightly modification to receive input from command line argument.

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* The calculation implemented below is not efficient
 * Consult numerical algorithm for better solutions
 */
void *
compute_prime(void *arg)
{
    int candidate = 2;
    int n = *((int *) arg);

    while (1)
    {
        int factor;
        int is_prime = 1;

        for (factor = 2; factor < candidate; ++factor)
            if (candidate % factor == 0)
            {
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        if (is_prime)
            if (--n == 0)
                return (void *)candidate;
        ++candidate;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int which_prime = atoi(argv[1]);
    int prime;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, &which_prime);
    pthread_join(thread, (void *)&prime);
    printf("The %dth prime number is %d.\n", which_prime, prime);

    return 0;
}
```

What confuses me is `pthread_join` function. Its prototype is

```c
pthread_join(pthread_t, void **)
```

So the second parameter is of type `void **`. While, in the program a variable of `void *` is passed. I think `(void *)&prime` does be a `void *`, right. But how can a `void *` be casted to `void **`? I checked the source code and the assignment to the second parameter is simply `*status = pthread->status`.

Is `void *` automatically casted to `void **`? I think this is not allowed but this program makes it seem to be possible. And is it ill-formed to write like this?

Comment: Dont understand the question properly, but generally it used like this: `void *prime;` `pthread_join(thread, &prime);`

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `pthread_join` is a pointer to a place to put the "exit value" of the thread you're joining with.  That exit value (the argument to `pthread_exit` or the value returned by your thread function passed to `pthread_create`) is a `void *`, so the argument to `pthread_join` is a `void **`.

Now the thing that is confusing is that in C, a `void *` can be implicitly converted to any pointer type without a cast.  So casting the value you're passing to `(void *)` then allows it to be implicitly converted to `void **` and passed.  The problem is that if the thing you are passing the address of is not actually a `void *`, you get undefined behavior.  In this example, on a 64-bit machine, a `void *` is 8 bytes while an `int` is likely only 4 bytes, so this might clobber whatever happens to be in the stack frame immediately after `prime`.  That might be `which_prime`, so this might print `The 0th prime is`... regardless of what value you initially passed.  Or it might print `0` for the prime on a big-endian machine.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect that a `void *` can be converted to `void **`. It's weird. I think more contemplation can be plunged into this question. But you do give me more inspiration to dive deeper

Answer (score 0):

With the help of other posts, I try to answer my own question.

There are two noteworthy points in the example:

1. in the thread function, the return statement is

   ```c
   return (void *)candidate;
   ```

   where `candidate` is actually a `int` but is converted to `void *`. This is not portable but C does allow this to happen. A type casting doesn't change underlying bits but change the way how the compiler interpret these bits. Here being a return value of type `void *` is fine as long as not dereference it. (But since a pointer may have different size with a int, this may or may not cause problem.)
2. in the main function, variable prime is declared as `int`, but converted to `void *` after taking the address of it. So 4 bytes (if `int` is of size 4) in the memory now is refereed by a temporary variable of type `void *`. But such temp variable doesn't really know nor care exactly how large the underlying memory is. The `void *` temp variable is just an entry point.

   When passed into `pthread_join`, the temporary variable (of type `void *`) mention above is implicitly converted to `void **`. Like #1, although this variable is not really a pointer to pointer, we can make compiler "think" it was such kind of type. A `void **` can be dereferenced twice but the second dereference definitely will lead to a segmentation fault error. But what's good is `pthread_join` only dereference it once. After the first dereference, the resulting type is `void *`, and is the same as the return type of `pthread_exit` and thread function. Therefore, compiler doesn't complain anything and does the assignment. However, on both sides of the assignment, what is `void *` is really a `int` if only consider 4 bytes out of 8 bytes. Therefore, when we retrieve the value from variable prime, a correct interpretation performed to these 4 bytes and a int result is displayed.

Clarification ends.

---

I think it's obscure to understand and difficult to give a coherent explanation, especially I'm not speaking English. Forgive me if this doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: Regarding your point 1: type casting very well may change the underlying bits.  It represents a *conversion of the value*, not a reinterpretation of its representation.  Casting an int to `void *` and returning it is fine, but it is not portable on account of the relationship between the original `int` and the returned pointer being implementation defined.  The relative sizes of `int` and `void *` do not factor in here, at least not directly.

Comment: Regarding your point 2: the original `int` is not converted.  *Its address (an `int *`) is what is converted*.  This conversion is allowed.  The result is implicitly converted again (to `void **` in the function call).  The description of how the expected value might be conveyed back to the caller is plausible, but in no way defined or required.  The program's behavior is undefined, even if `int` and `void *` are the same size.  It is in no way safe to assume that it will work as intended.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your explanation. Type casting may include more amount of bits but the value on each bit doesn't change. Is this right?

Comment: Such a thorough comprehension may exceed the original purpose of the author. It is used to exemplify "return value from thread". I believe this writing style is not recommended but good for the grasp of C.

Comment: No, it is *not* necessarily correct that a typecast leaves any bits unchanged.in general. It is rather unlikely to do so in `(float) 1`, for example.  Nor is it necessarily correct for any particular non-trivial case, such as casting (integer type) `uintptr_t` to pointer type `void *`, even if the sizes of the two types match, as they probably do in that case.  Even conversions between different-size integer types will not conserve bits if the representations are big-endian.  Casts express explicit *conversions*, not *reinterpretations*.

Comment: It is possible for casts to produce results that have representations partially or even wholly matching the original value's, even systematically so, but where that happens, it is a characteristic of a specific C implementation, not in any way guaranteed by the language itself.  Under most circumstances, it is unwise to rely on implementation characteristics, and in the area of trying to interpret data of one type as if it had a different type, it is positively dangerous.

Comment: Inasmuch as I assume that the author of *Advanced Linux Programming* intended to teach good programming practices, the details of their example are at best questionable, even if we accept that it was a reasonable assumption at the time that pointers and `int`s were the same size.  Nowadays, when it is common for that assumption to be wrong, the example is just plain wrong.